# Access array inside JSON object using Axios Vue JS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I need to access arrays inside JSON object and save into different arrays. I tried few ways but no luck.
I could get all other values without any problem but when it comes to arrays I couldn't retrieve those.

I feel the way I try to access arrays inside JSON object might be wrong and but I couldn't figure it out

Here is JSON object

```
{
   "packId":51,
   "shortCode":"TTY",
   "packDescription":"TTY Des",
   "startDate":"2020-09-01",
   "endDate":"2020-09-08",
   "validityValue":30,
   "validityType":"Hours",
   "expiryAction":true,
   "expirySMS":64,
   "activationSMS":64,
   "deactivationSMS":64,
   "subscriptionSMS":0,
   "deactivationAction":true,
   "deactivationShortCode":"DEACT TTY",
   "deprovisionOnExpiry":true,
   "deleteByPackType":true,
   "packType":{
      "packTypeId":2,
      "name":"Facebook"
   },
   "timeBands":[
      {
         "timeBandId":1,
         "start":"8:00",
         "end":"23:00",
         "timeBand":"8:00-23:00"
      },
      {
         "timeBandId":2,
         "start":"8:00",
         "end":"20:00",
         "timeBand":"8:00-20:00"
      }
   ],
   "activationTypes":[
      {
         "activationTypeId":1,
         "name":"SMS"
      },
      {
         "activationTypeId":2,
         "name":"Web"
      }
   ],
   "channels":[
      {
         "channelId":1,
         "name":"hShenid"
      },
      {
         "channelId":2,
         "name":"Genesis"
      }
   ],
   "users":[
      
   ]
}
```

Axios Call

```
getPackById(id)
{
  return axios.get(`${API_URL}/pack/get/${id}`);
}

 refreshPack()
{
  
  PackComposeDataService.getPackById(this.id).then((res)=>
  {

      

      //I can access these values without any problem

      this.deleteByPackType= res.data.deleteByPackType,
      this.packTypeValues=res.data.packType,
      this.shortCode= res.data.shortCode,
      this.packDescription= res.data.packDescription,
      this.startDate= res.data.startDate,
      this.endDate= res.data.endDate,
      this.subscriptionSMS= res.data.subsNotificationValues["id"],
      this.validityValue= res.data.validityValue,
      this.validityType= res.data.validityType,
      this.actionOnExpiry= res.data.expiryAction,
      this.expirySMS= res.data.expiryNotificationValues,
      this.activationSMS= res.data.activationNotificationValues,
      this.deactivationAction= res.data.deactivationAction,
      this.deactivationShortCode= res.data.deactivationShortCode,
      this.deactivationSMS= res.data.deactivationNotificationValues,
      this.deprovisionOnExpiry= res.data.deprovisionOnExpiry,


      //I need to get these arrays
      this.timeBandValues= res.data.timeBands,
      this.activationTypes= res.data.activationTypes,
      this.channels= res.data.channels,
      this.users= res.data.users

      

  });
```

Comment: If you can get `res.data.endDate`, why would you not be able to get `res.data.timeBands` ? And the first object in this array is `res.data.timeBands[0]` and the id of the first timeBand is `res.data.timeBands[0].timeBandId` So, whats your question?

Comment: @derpirscher endDate endDate just a field not arrray. but timeBands is array. I think you made a mistake. please check it carefully

Comment: in the response you are showing `res.data.timeBands` is an array. You know how to access elements of an array? If not you should start learning the basics  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Yeah, `timeBands` is an array. So why wouldn't you be able to access it or the elements in the array? What do you want to put into `this.timeBandValues`?

Comment: From the above code, you should be able to access the arrays normally. Maybe the problem is elsewhere. It `timeBandValues` defined somewhere in your component data?
Also try console logging to cross-check

Comment: First thing: I think you don't need all the trailing commas. Second: what does a `console.log(res.data.timeBands)` tell you about it?

Comment: @Pipetus the trailing commas could actually be the problem

Comment: I could find out issue. After this code section this.subscriptionSMS= res.data.subsNotificationValues["id"], other part of code didn't work properly since it was wrong field name and when I put timeBands above that line of code it worked. I @Pipetus  don't have experience in javascript but I feel that is painful , work part of code until wrong part even didnt load console.log. I think I dont know the basic of javascript that might be the reason I face this kind of error. I really appreciate your time and support this means a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to take only the `timeBand` string of each of the arrays (or the `activationType`, eventually).

If that's the case, you may want to `map` to convert each object in the array to a simple string:

```js
// ...
this.timeBandValues = res.data.timeBands.map(o => o.timeBand) // you're going to get ["8:00-23:00", "8:00-20:00"]
// ...
```

Comment: I need whole array : this.timeBandValues = [
      {
         "timeBandId":1,
         "start":"8:00",
         "end":"23:00",
         "timeBand":"8:00-23:00"
      },
      {
         "timeBandId":2,
         "start":"8:00",
         "end":"20:00",
         "timeBand":"8:00-20:00"
      }
   ]

Comment: @HashanR and thats exactly what `this.timeBandValues = res.data.timeBands` does.

Comment: Yes I need to get exact array no need to filter or do anything. problem is that I can't get it. I could get all other values but none of arrays.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct name of the property? Maybe it isn't contained in the answer? If there is a property named `timeBands` in `res.data` you can get it via `res.data.timeBands`, regardless of its type. Have you tried debugging and inspecting the `res.data` object if it really contains a `timeBands` property?

Comment: Yes I have correct names I could get other data without any issue and even console statement not printing I don't know reason. Appreciate for your kind support! I'm still searching what went to wrong

Comment: Did you call just `console.log(res.data.timeBands)` or `console.log(res.data)`? If printing out the whole data object works, but not printing just the `timeBands` then your result does not contain this property and you have to check the server, why it does not add this property to the result.

Comment: @derpirscher I could find out issue. After this code section this.subscriptionSMS= res.data.subsNotificationValues["id"], other part of code didn't work properly since it was wrong field name and when I put timeBands above that line of code it worked. I don't have experience in javascript but I feel that is painful , work part of code until wrong part even didnt load console.log. I think I dont know the basic of javascript that might be the reason I face this kind of error. I really appreciate your time and support this means a lot!